# neural network not training correctly

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation, c

i'm trying to learn how a neural network works. i'm writing the neural network in C for handwritten digit recognition and training it on MNIST dataset. the neural network has an input layer with 28*28 neurons, an hidden layer with 50 neurons, and an output layer with 10 neurons. the activation function is sigmoid. weights and biases are initialized randomly between -0.5 and +0.5. i tried implementing forward propagation and back propagation but i think i'm doing something wrong. the training seems not to work well because the accuracy is not that good and sometimes it decrease while training. the learning rate is set to 0.01 and reducing it to 0.001 didn't change much (it had almost the same behavior)
Example:
`EPOCH: 0        ACCURACY: 63.180000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 6318`
`EPOCH: 1        ACCURACY: 63.640000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 6364`
`EPOCH: 2        ACCURACY: 67.730000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 6773`
`EPOCH: 3        ACCURACY: 68.530000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 6853`
`EPOCH: 4        ACCURACY: 71.160000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 7116`
`EPOCH: 5        ACCURACY: 76.120000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 7612`
`EPOCH: 6        ACCURACY: 81.080000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 8108`
`EPOCH: 7        ACCURACY: 81.410000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 8141`
`EPOCH: 8        ACCURACY: 78.440000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 7844`
`EPOCH: 9        ACCURACY: 77.910000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 7791`
`EPOCH: 10       ACCURACY: 82.070000     CORRECT ANSWERS: 8207`

Here is the back propagation function:

```
void BackPropagation(double *input,double *output){
double hidden_gradients[NUMHIDDEN];
double output_gradients[NUMOUTPUTS];
    
    for(int i=0;i<NUMOUTPUTS;i++)
        output_gradients[i]=(output[i]-output_layer[i])*dSigmoid(output_layer[i]);

    for(int i=0;i<NUMOUTPUTS;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<NUMHIDDEN;j++)
            output_layer_weights[i][j]+=LR*output_gradients[i]*hidden_layer[j];
        output_layer_bias[i]+=LR*output_gradients[i];
    } 

    for(int i=0;i<NUMHIDDEN;i++){
        double sum=0.0;
        for(int j=0;j<NUMOUTPUTS;j++)
            sum+=output_gradients[j]*output_layer_weights[j][i];
        hidden_gradients[i]=dSigmoid(hidden_layer[i])*sum;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<NUMHIDDEN;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<NUMINPUTS;j++)
            hidden_layer_weights[i][j]+=LR*hidden_gradients[i]*input[j];
        hidden_layer_bias[i]+=LR*hidden_gradients[i];
    }

}
```

i'll leave here also the forward propagation function:

```
void ForwardPropagation(double *input){

    for(int i=0;i<NUMHIDDEN;i++){
        hidden_layer[i]=hidden_layer_bias[i];
        for(int j=0;j<NUMINPUTS;j++)
            hidden_layer[i]+=input[j]*hidden_layer_weights[i][j];
        hidden_layer[i]=sigmoid(hidden_layer[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<NUMOUTPUTS;i++){
        output_layer[i]=output_layer_bias[i];
        for(int j=0;j<NUMHIDDEN;j++)
            output_layer[i]+=hidden_layer[j]*output_layer_weights[i][j];
        output_layer[i]=sigmoid(output_layer[i]);
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: 82% seems a good accuracy, what is the issue ? Just do more epochs .

Comment: is it normal that the accuracy decrease sometimes? because I was wondering if my implementation was wrong, because I tried also a version i found online and the accuracy was never decreasing

Comment: It can happen as the training is usually done in a stochastic way, and you are not optimizing on a smooth surface either. However it should increase on average otherwise you probably have an error or a learning rate which lead to divergence... Also here you are only given the accuracy, not the loss. The network is only aware of the loss, not accuracy.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try with more epochs and I will try to compute the loss

Comment: You already have the loss otherwise how could you train it ?

Comment: oh yes, it's `target_output[i]-output_layer[i]` right? that should be only for one input image, the total loss is the sum of the loss of every input?

Comment: Usually we look at the mean loss , so that the loss value does not depend on batch size or epoch size

Comment: i reviewed the code again and after finding some errors, (for example computing the activations instantly in the forward propagation, instead of when i needed them), i was able to get ~95% accuracy on test inputs and ~96% accuracy on training inputs. thanks again for the help